# PickerView didSelectRow when selecting it will Crash and shows (lldb) error

Tags: ios, xcode6, uipickerview

I am creating custom view, in that i added picker, when `did selected` Row at index  method after selecting i will removed the picker from superView, but App will crashing. if will not remove from `superview` it will not crash. what can i do Please suggest me .

I will using picker when textfield selecting

```
 _rUsername=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 270, self.view.frame.size.width-30, 30)];
            _rUsername.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
            _rUsername.placeholder=@"Gander";
            [_rUsername addTarget:self action:@selector(showPicker)forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidBegin];
[_registerView addSubview:_rUsername];
```

now problem in Picker methods

```
-(void) showPicker
{
    [_rUsername resignFirstResponder];
   UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30,230,220,0)];

    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    [_registerView addSubview:pickerView];
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [_arrayNo count];
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView     {
    return 1;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
     return [_arrayNo objectAtIndex:row];
}
- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    int sectionWidth = 300;
    return sectionWidth;
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

    _rUsername.text=[_arrayNo objectAtIndex:row];
     [pickerView removeFromSuperview];

}
```

Here if i removed `[pickerView removeFromSuperview];` from `didselectRow` method it will working fine, but i want after selecting picker must remove from the superview. if it will not then crashed and shows error "(lldb)" like this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to the following:

```
pickerView.hidden = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this - 
[pickerView setHidden:YES];